# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.match.params.id'

Tags: axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I have created one React app. For data fetching, I used axios. My app works fine as expected. But in my terminal, I am getting warning like this `Line 34:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.match.params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. I don't want to use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. Is there any alternative solution?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/students/" + props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          birthday: response.data.birthday,
          address: response.data.address,
          zipcode: response.data.zipcode,
          city: response.data.city,
          phone: response.data.phone,
          email: response.data.email
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to disable the eslint rule, you need to follow it, simply add the prop to your dependency array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/students/" + props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          birthday: response.data.birthday,
          address: response.data.address,
          zipcode: response.data.zipcode,
          city: response.data.city,
          phone: response.data.phone,
          email: response.data.email
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }, [props.match.params.id]);
```

This means that if the id changes, your effect will be unmounted and called again, which seems to make sense, considering the match.params.id is used inside your effect.